# Access Denied on installing WSP having Web Application scoped Feature

Tags: feature, solution-package, installation

As the title says. I am trying to deploy a solution through central admin which has a Web Application scoped feature. As soon as I try to install it, it goes to access denied page.

Strangely, when I change the scope of the feature to Site, it installs successfully.

Is it something related to improper permissions?